# Hold oracle DB connection between bash and python

Tags: python, bash, oracle, cx-oracle

I have a bash script which calls a python script to create the Oracle DB connection using cx_oracle. I want to use the same connection object from bash script later as well. But whenever the python script ends, connection object is lost.
Can anyone help to hold the connection object to use further in the bash or can we pass the connection object from python to bash and vice versa!!

Comment: I don't think what you are describing is possible. You should consider a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reconsider your architecture and use some kind of service or web app that remains running.

Connections are made up of (i) a cx_Oracle data structure (ii) a network connection to the database (iii) a database server process.

Once the Python process is closed, then all three are closed by default.  So you lose all state like the statement cache, and any session settings like NLS date format.  If you enable Database Resident Connection Pooling (DRCP) - see the [manual](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#database-resident-connection-pooling-drcp) - then the database server process will remain available for re-use which saves some overhead, however the next process will  still have to re-authenticate.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, any way if i leave python then again connection building is required. thanks for the suggestions.